# Installing SNMP using Server 16.04 LTS

Tags: server, software-installation, 16.04, snmp

I just recently installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on VMware Workstation for a school project. OS installed beautifully; however, when I try to install SNMP on it, I am getting this message:

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled 'Ubuntu-xxx 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd 64 (20160420.3)' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]"
```

I have tried running an update, re-installing Ubuntu, but still nothing.

I have a x64-big Intel Celeron processor on my PC but according to documentation, the image should be compatible. I did install from a USB-stick though. Could that be the reason why? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to install using apt-get, I would disable the cdrom from apt.  'sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list' comment out the cdrom, and apt-get update, then install

Comment: Awesome. I will give this a try Brian. I'm fairly new to Linux, let me see if I can figure out how to comment out that CDrom. If not I will bug you with help on that. Thanks a lot!